# Core Location for a Execution Group o Server in IIB v10.0.0.19

Tags: heap-memory, coredump, messagebroker, heap-dump, ibm-integration-bus

What is the location of a core dump file created by IBM Integration Bus (IIB) or WebSphere Message Broker (WMB)? and How can I modify the file path?

My IIB version is: 10.0.0.19

The documentation read is older. Added consulted links.

https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005phqcWCAQ/how-can-i-redirect-corejavaheap-dump-to-different-location-other-than-varmqsi?language=es

https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062k8jS/what-is-the-path-of-the-core-dump-file-created-by-iib?language=es

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the information in the below IBM links for v10:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=troubleshooting-dumps
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=troubleshooting-abend-files

Comment: Hi... Currently, I'm working to tunne the JVM argument into some Servers (Execution Groups) in IIB.... For me the response it isn't clear.... I mean, my question is: By default, WMB/IIB sends coredumps, javacores and heapdumps to the /var/mqsi directory. This might cause the Integration Nodes to fail due to the lack of space. How can I redirect these dump files to another location?

Comment: I think the first of the two links that you posted answers that question : 
https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005phqcWCAQ/how-can-i-redirect-corejavaheap-dump-to-different-location-other-than-varmqsi

Comment: You can check the following link on how to change the workpath : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=resources-changing-location-work-path